# Need to move data from cols 4,56 to the bottom of 1,2,3, and columns 7,8,9 to bottom of 1,2,3

Tags: merge

I have found some code, although cant remember where from, which works apart from one problem, in the data, I have numbers with leading 0's ie 0045, I need to keep the 0's, what happens is 0045 gets moved to the bottom of columns 1,2,3, which is want I want but loses the 0's so now says 45 not 0045.

Can anyone help me alter this code to preserve the formatting, I'm still learning and not sure how to change this to do that.
Many thanks
Andy

Sub moveColumnsData456()

```
Dim sourceLastRow As Long
Dim destLastRow As Long
Dim lastColumn As Long
Dim i As Long
Dim sourceRng As Range
Dim destRng As Range
Dim a As Range

With ActiveSheet
    lastColumn = .UsedRange.Columns(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count).Column
    ' not sure if I can put this - .NumberFormat = "@"
    'loop through every set of 3 columns
    For i = 15 To lastColumn Step 9
        sourceLastRow = .Range(.Columns(i), .Columns(i + 15)).Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).row

        'incase columns BCD are blank then set last row=1
        Set a = .Columns("F:N").Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
        If Not a Is Nothing Then
            destLastRow = a.row + 1
        Else
            destLastRow = 1
        End If

        'no need to use copy/paste, just let the range equals to each other
        Set sourceRng = .Range(.Cells(1, i), .Cells(sourceLastRow, i + 8))
        
        .Cells(destLastRow, "F").Resize(sourceRng.Rows.Count, sourceRng.Columns.Count) = sourceRng.Value
    

    Next

    'uncomment below to clear all columns besides BCD
    .Range(.Columns("N"), .Columns(lastColumn)).Clear
End With

End Sub
```